# How to get a specific content from a URL

Tags: shell, unix, wget

I want to recursively hit the below URL with different tracking numbers and get only the shipment status from the URL

UPS URL: **https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=123456789012345678&requester=WT/trackdetails**

[Sample Status of Tracking Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPROk.png)

I tried wget command but its not able to load the whole file and its of no use to me and curl doesnt work in my system.

`wget --no-check-certificate --output-document ttt.htm "$UPS_URL"`

Any other workaround for this would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this since it is off-topic here. More related to SuperUser.

Comment: url may redirecting to other url. use ```curl -k -v -L``` for redirecting sites

Comment: edited the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong page and request method for getting the data. I visited the page you linked to, it simply contains a text box where you can add the shipment numbers and then it redirects you to a page with the results.

So, simply calling Wget on this page will do nothing. You need to know the precise URI to call to for getting the details. I opened Network Tools on my browser and saw the network requests. Upon clicking submit, it sends a `POST` request and the response to it contains all the data you need. Extracting from there, I built this request:

```
$ cat ups-request
{
  "Locale": "en_US",
  "TrackingNumber": [
    "45234534263"
  ]
}
```

This is a JSON string with all the package numbers you want to track. You could even add more numbers (the website claims it can handle upto 25 together). Once the file is ready, call Wget:

```
$ wget --method=POST --body-file=ups-request --header="Content-Type: application/json" "https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US"
```

In this, we build the Wget command by asking it to send a POST request (`--method=POST`), sending the JSON request we've created in the body (`--body-file=ups-request`), and telling Wget that the request is of type JSON (`--header="Content-Type: application/json"`). The server then replies back with the full details of the request:

```
{
  "statusCode": "200",
  "statusText": "Successful",
  "isLoggedInUser": false,
  "trackedDateTime": "02/14/2019 7:53 A.M. EST",
  "isBcdnMultiView": false,
  "trackDetails": [
    {
      "errorCode": "504",
      "errorText": "Tracking number not found in database",
      "requestedTrackingNumber": "45234534263",
      "trackingNumber": "45234534263",
      "isMobileDevice": false,
      "packageStatus": null,
      "packageStatusType": null,
      "packageStatusCode": null,
      "progressBarType": null,
      "progressBarPercentage": null,
      "simplifiedText": null,
      "scheduledDeliveryDayCMSKey": null,
      "scheduledDeliveryDate": null,
      "noEstimatedDeliveryDateLabel": null,
      "scheduledDeliveryTime": null,
      "scheduledDeliveryTimeEODLabel": null,
      "packageCommitedTime": null,
      "endOfDayResCMSKey": null,
      "deliveredDayCMSKey": null,
      "deliveredDate": null,
      "deliveredTime": null,
      "receivedBy": null,
      "leaveAt": null,
      "leftAt": null,
      "shipToAddress": null,
      "shipFromAddress": null,
      "consigneeAddress": null,
      "signatureTrackingUrl": null,
      "trackHistoryDescription": null,
      "additionalInformation": null,
      "specialInstructions": null,
      "proofOfDeliveryUrl": null,
      "upsAccessPoint": null,
      "additionalPackagesCount": null,
      "attentionNeeded": null,
      "shipmentProgressActivities": null,
      "trackingNumberType": null,
      "preAuthorizedForReturnData": null,
      "shipToAddressLblKey": null,
      "trackSummaryView": null,
      "senderShipperNumber": null,
      "internalKey": null,
      "userOptions": null,
      "sendUpdatesOptions": null,
      "myChoiceUpSellLink": null,
      "bcdnNumber": null,
      "promo": null,
      "whatsNextText": null,
      "packageStatusTimeLbl": null,
      "packageStatusTime": null,
      "myChoiceToken": null,
      "showMycTerms": false,
      "showConfirmWindow": false,
      "confirmWindowLbl": null,
      "confirmWindowLink": null,
      "followMyDelivery": null,
      "fileClaim": null,
      "viewClaim": null,
      "flightInformation": null,
      "voyageInformation": null,
      "viewDeliveryReceipt": null
    }
  ]
}
```